# Cannot understand Scala method definition

Tags: scala, playframework

This is some code from Alvin Alexander's minimal Scala Websocket server.

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.streams.ActorFlow
import javax.inject.Inject
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.Materializer
import models.SimpleWebSocketActor
import play.api.libs.json._

class WebSocketsController @Inject() (cc: ControllerComponents)(implicit system: ActorSystem)
extends AbstractController(cc)
{

    def index = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
        logger.info("index page was called")
        Ok(views.html.index())
    }
}
```

What I'm curious about is the method definition for `index`. The notation is different to the normal method definition I've seen in Scala. Could someone explain what is going on here, and possibly point to some docs on this syntax? I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: There is nothing different to it, `index` is a method that takes no arguments and whose body is `Action { ... }`

Comment: And what is `Action { ... }`?

Comment: `Action` is an `object` probably imported from here: `play.api.mvc._` and you are calling its `apply` method which seems to expect a function from `Request[T]` to something _(probably some kind of `Response` type defined by **play**)_, you are then passing a lambda to that method to create such function and you are marking the argument of that lambda as an `implicit` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definition is a combination of several syntax features of Scala but in the end there's nothing that special about it.

It's equivalent to something like this:

```scala
def index = {
  
  def handleRequest(request: Request[AnyContent]) = {
    implicit req = request

    logger.info("index page was called")
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }

  Action.apply(handleRequest) // Replaced by Action(...), then Action { ... }
}
```